# Why process wasn't killed after closing SSH connection

Tags: linux, ssh, kill, nohup

I launched this command via SSH on a Debian server:

```
watch --precise -n 1 top -b -n 1 -p 27330 | tail -n 1 | awk "{print \$9}" >> 27330.log &
```

After a while I quit my terminal. When I connected again the process was still running. Shouldn't the process be killed? I thought that the only way to keep a process running is to use `nohup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & at the end of your command makes it run in the background. Therefore, when you quit your SSH session, it will keep running.

Also read https://superuser.com/a/152695/228108 (the comments mainly).

Comment: This explains how SSHD manages this  http://superuser.com/questions/662431/what-exactly-determines-if-a-backgrounded-job-is-killed-when-the-shell-is-exited